# How to get the standard deviation from the fitted distribution in scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, data-fitting

I'm trying to fit multiple distributions and get the standard deviation for each. However plenty distributions retrun either inf or Nan for the standard deviation. Is the way of getting the variance of the fitted distribution that I'm doing is correct? Is there a better way? why the Nans?  This is what I have done:

```
param = distribution.fit(data)
arg = param[:-2]
loc = param[-2]
scale = param[-1]

if len(arg)>0:
     std = np.sqrt(distribution.stats(arg, loc, scale, moments='v')[0]))
else:
     std = np.sqrt(distribution.stats(loc, scale, moments='v')[0]))
```

Also I skip distributions that generate a warning while fitting the data.

Update 1: 
For instance, when `distribution = scipy.stats.beta`, I get `[ nan  nan]` and the parameters are as follows:

```
arg: (32.198726690922953, 15883184.284202889)
loc: -33527.5754686
scale: 35484135514.4
```

Comment: Please give more details.  Provide `data`, and show *which* distribution gives `inf` or `nan`.

Comment: Thanks @WarrenWeckesser for the reminder, I'll add the distributions to the question but is my code correct? or there is a better way to get the standard deviation of my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked a different question on Stack Overflow and got a solution that answered this question too. It turned out that the parameters that I have passed were interpreted differently by scipy. Here is the link to the answers:

[isinfmu-error-in-scipy-stats-when-calling-std-for-exponweib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200669/isinfmu-error-in-scipy-stats-when-calling-std-for-exponweib/41202939#41202939)

Answer (score 0):

The [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) of a beta distribution is:

```
a * b / [ (a + b)^2 * (a + b + 1) ]
```

So the standard deviation is the square root of that. To get `a` and `b`:

```
a = scipy.stats.beta.fit(data)[0]
b = scipy.stats.beta.fit(data)[1]
```

Note that you can **always** calculate the standard deviation of your data (absent any fitted distribution) using `np.std(data)`.

Comment: I know but I'm iterating over a list of distributions. Hence, I was looking for a general way of doing this that works on any distribution, something builtin.