# isinf(mu) error in Scipy stats when calling std for exponweib?

Tags: standard-deviation, scipy

I have been getting this error when I call std on a frozen exponweib  distribution?

Here is the code:

```
d = st.exponweib
params = d.fit(y)

arg = params[:-2]
loc = params[-2]
scale = params[-1]

rv1 = d(arg,loc,scale)

print rv1.std()
```

The parameters after fitting are:

> arg: (3.445136651705262, 0.10885378466279112)
>
> loc: 11770.05
>
> scale: 3.87424773976

Here is the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-637-4394814bbb8c> in <module>()
     11 rv1 = d(arg,loc,scale)
     12 
---> 13 print rv1.std()

.../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.pyc in std(self)
    487 
    488     def std(self):
--> 489         return self.dist.std(*self.args, **self.kwds)
    490 
    491     def moment(self, n):

.../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.pyc in std(self, *args, **kwds)
   1259         """
   1260         kwds['moments'] = 'v'
-> 1261         res = sqrt(self.stats(*args, **kwds))
   1262         return res
   1263 

.../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.pyc in stats(self, *args, **kwds)
   1032                         mu = self._munp(1, *goodargs)
   1033                     mu2 = mu2p - mu * mu
-> 1034                     if np.isinf(mu):
   1035                         # if mean is inf then var is also inf
   1036                         mu2 = np.inf

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Please let me what is wrong with what I'm doing or how to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exponweib` distribution has two required parameters `a`, `c` and two optional, `loc` and `scale`. When you call `d(arg, loc, scale)` the result is that `arg` is interpreted as `a`, `loc` is interpreted as `c`, and `scale` is interpreted as `loc`. And since your `arg` is a tuple of two elements, you end up with a tuple of random variables, neither of which is what you want.

Solution: unpack the tuple: `d(*arg, loc, scale)`. Or even simpler, use

```
rv1 = d(*params)
```

which unpacks all the parameters for you, without you having to extract and name them.

---

By the way, when you want to provide your own loc and scale of a random variable, it's better to pass them as named arguments, like `d(3, 5, loc=90, scale=0.3)`. This avoids the situation you encountered, when some of these parameters get interpreted as something else because you didn't get some argument right. In your example, `d(arg, loc=loc, scale=scale)` would immediately throw an error, "missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'" instead of taking loc instead of c.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out by trial and error but couldn't understand the reason. Thank you very much, well explained.